# How to pass a variable to a redirect?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to pass the date to another page using the redirect method and I get an error of `undefined variable`.

Here is my controller

```
$exam_last = ExamResult::latest()->first();
$date_achived =$exam_last->created_at;

return redirect()->route('certificate',  [$courses, $request, $course_id, $date_achived])
->with('success', 'Congratulations you\'ve passed! Your final results are '.$get_final_score. '%' )
->with( [$date_achived] );
```

Here is my blade

```
<div class="CompletionDate">{{$date_achived->created_at}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try returning the view and the data as `key => value`:

```
$date_achived =$exam_last->created_at;

return view('admin.courses.certificate_one_template')
        ->with(['courses' => $courses, 'request' => $request, 'course_id' => $course_id, 'date_achived' => $date_achived])
        ->with('success', 'Congratulations you\'ve passed! Your final results are '.$get_final_score. '%');
```

In blade use `$date_achived` instead `$date_achived->created_at`:

```
<div class="CompletionDate">{{$date_achived}}</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much for answering. I still get the same error

Comment: sorry, I updated the answer, I didn't see is date_achived what you want

Comment: itś on `$date_achived` th error? do you changed `$date_achived->created_at` to `$date_achived` in the view?

Comment: I made all the changes in both the controller and the view.

Comment: Here is what it says Undefined variable: date_achived (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/QuickHS/resources/views/admin/courses/certificate_one_template.blade.php)

Comment: I also tested in tinker, and there it pulls the right data, that's why I think is in the redirect

Comment: The error was in the entire function, thank you so much

Comment: but it worked? you do not need to mark it as accepted if it is not the one that answers your question

Comment: No it worked. You were right. There was a secondary issue in addition to the one you discovered.